# Dask delayed function call with non-passed parameters

Tags: python, dask, configparser, dask-delayed

I am seeking to better understand the following behavior when using `dask.delayed` to call a function that depends on parameters. The issue seems to arise when parameters are specified in a parameters file read by configparser. Here is a complete example:

parameter file:

```
#zpar.ini: parameter file for configparser

[my pars]
my_zpar = 2.
```

parser:

```
#zippy_parser
import configparser

def read(_rundir):

    global rundir
    rundir = _rundir

    cp = configparser.ConfigParser()
    cp.read(rundir + '/zpar.ini')

    #[my pars]
    global my_zpar
    my_zpar = cp['my pars'].getfloat('my_zpar')
```

and the main python file:

```
# dask test with configparser
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client
import zippy_parser as zpar


def my_func(x, y):

    # print stuff
    print("parameter from main is: {}".format(main_par))
    print("parameter from configparser is: {}".format(zpar.my_zpar))

    # do stuff
    return x + y


if __name__ == '__main__':

    client = Client(n_workers = 4)

    #read parameters from input file
    rundir = '/path/to/parameter/file'
    zpar.read(rundir)

    #test zpar
    print("zpar is {}".format(zpar.my_zpar))

    #define parameter and call my_func
    main_par = 5.
    z = dask.delayed(my_func)(1., 2.)
    z.compute()

    client.close()
```

The first print statement in my_func() executes just fine, but the second print statement raises an exception. The output is:

> ```
> zpar is 2.0
> parameter from main is: 5.0
> distributed.worker - WARNING -  Compute Failed
> Function:  my_func
> args:      (1.0, 2.0)
> kwargs:    {}
> Exception: AttributeError("module 'zippy_parser' has no attribute 'my_zpar'",)
> ```

I am new to dask. I suppose this has something to do with the serialization, which I do not understand. Can someone enlighten me and/or point to relevant documentation? Thanks!

Comment: You example is complex (many files, a lot of redirection), but incomplete :| For example, zippy.py does not define `_zippy_sum_array` and cannot import `zippy_parser` or `zstuff` as written, unless you are in the right directory; and `read` is never called.

Comment: Oh dear. I know. I was trying to include what I thought were the essentials without making the post even longer. I will try to condense my example.

Comment: @mdurant Thanks for the feedback. I edited the original post. Should be complete, simpler, and still gets at the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to keep this brief.

When a function is serialised in order to be sent to workers, python also sends local variables and functions needed by the function (its "closure"). However, it stores the modules it references by name, it does not try to serialise your whole runtime.
This means that `zippy_parser` is *imported* in the worker, not deserialised. Since the function `read` has never been called 
in the worker, the `global` variable is never initialised.

So, you could call `read` in the workers as part of your function or otherwise, but probably the pattern or setting module-global variables from with a function isn't great. Dask's delayed mechanism prefers functional purity, that the result you get should not depend on the current state of the runtime.

(note that if you had created the client after calling `read` in the main script, the workers *might* have got the in-memory version, depending on how subprocesses are configured to be created on your system)

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to pass in all parameters to your dask delayed functions explicitly, rather than relying on the global namespace.